# Django server: execute a function once a day

Tags: python, django, api, server, backend

I have a `django model`, and every object of that model needs to use another api and each needs to have an access token to use another api's resources. In order to use the api, i need to pass `access token`. And I have `refresh token` which expires after `two weeks`. What I want to do is to define a `function` that checks if refresh token expires that day and if so, update tokens. Most importantly, I want to call that function `once a day`.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
   access_token = models.CharField(...)
   refresh_token = models.CharField(...)
   refresh_token_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(...)

   # Overriding save method so that whenever object is created it 
   # registers setInterval as well to update its tokens
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # register the update_tokens to run once every day

   def update_tokens(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # compare self.refresh_token_expiry_date with today
       if expires_today:
          # update
```

I can do that with `setInterval` in javascript, but what is the most efficient and safest way to implement that feature with `python` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's an overkill for what you need but you can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to do so.

Do the setup and declare the task with the interval that you deserve, in this case every day.